# How to check entered all values are white spaces or not?

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, textfield

I have a problem with validation in textField.
if I enter all values in textField are white space, it should throw a validation error when i pressed submit button.
I tried to resolve with isEmpty but not working.

```
TextFormField textField(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
        maxLines: 10,
        minLines: 6,
        controller: _noteTextController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius:
                  BorderRadius.circular(screenAwareSize(3, 6, context)),
              gapPadding: 0,
            ),
            hintText: 'Enter Note'),
        onSaved: (value) {
          //store your value here
        },
        validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Notes can\'t be empty';
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        });
  }
```

Comment: try to trim the value(text) before checking isEmpty.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I know , I have asked silly question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trim the value before checking.

```
validator: (value) {
  if (value.trim().isEmpty)
    return "Notes can't be empty";

  return null;
}
```

(This was also suggested by Harsha Pulikollu as a comment, not sure why it wasn't added as an answer)